# Error Message in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this code in my page:

```
 protected void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Session["truck_id"] = truck_id;
      Session["user_id"] = user_id;
      Session["usertype"] = usertype;
      if (usertype == "viewer")
      {
          Response.Write("Sorry, you do not have access to this page.");
          Response.StatusCode = 401;
          Response.End();
      }
      Response.Redirect("JobOrderForm.aspx");
}
```

I have logged in as viewer and the error message is this

[image]

How can I change it to `Unauthorized Access`?

Comment: you don't have this page and redirected page in same folder

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

Comment: `Response.Redirect("~/JobOrderForm.aspx");`

Comment: `/Login.aspx` Page Error :P, See The Message Closely.

Comment: Is `JobOrderForm.aspx` on root ?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Response.Redirect("JobOrderForm.aspx");
```

To this:

```
Response.Redirect("/JobOrderForm.aspx");
```

`/` refers to the root directory. This may help because probably this page and redirected page is not in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on your page. Have you tried debugging it? Set a breakpoint on the first line in the `btn_add_Click` method and step through to see which line is causing the error.